# CSRF token not working?

Tags: csrf-protection

Hi I am currently working **CSRFGuard 3** ,Token Validating propely but I am getting  below error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to locate expected parameter Message
at org.owasp.csrfguard.action.AbstractAction.getParameter(AbstractAction.java:61)
at org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.execute(Log.java:44)
at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuard.isValidRequest(CsrfGuard.java:373)
at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please check my code below

**Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties**

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger
org.owasp.csrfguard.ProtoctedMethod=POST,PUT,DELETE
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.Rotate=false
org.owasp.csrfguard.Ajax=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log
org.owasp.csrfguard.Log.Message=potential cross-site request forgery attack    thwarted(user %user%, ip %remote_ip%)
org.owasp.csrfguard.Redirect=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=OWASP_CSRFTOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=OWASP_CSRFTOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenLength=32
org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG=SHA1PRNG
**org.owasp.csrfguard.Protect=false** 
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.index=/contectpath/index.jsp
```

**When mark org.owasp.csrfguard.Protect=true .Token Validation method it self not calling.**

**web.xml**

```
        <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

While clicking F12 I am able to see **csrf:token-value** value.

Any one help me.What I did mistake

Answer (score 0):

The configuration example from the [OWASP Blog](http://owaspcsrfguard3.blogspot.com/2015/04/owasp-csrfguard-3.html) is incorrect.  The Log action's "Message" parameter needs to be changed from org.owasp.csrfguard.Log.Message= to org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.Message=   **.action** is missing from that property.

Config Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Configuration